# StructureMap.Pipeline.ObjectInstance.cs throwing error "The type initializer for 'Sample.Customer.CustomerSessionFactory' threw an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, typeinitializeexception

I am getting exception "`The type initializer for 'Sample.Customer.CustomerSessionFactory' threw an exception.`"  at line:

```
using (var customerDao = CustomerSessionFactory.CreateCustomerSession())
```

with inner exception

> Message: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: anObject
>   ParamName: anObject
>   Source: StructureMap

StackTrace:

> at StructureMap.Pipeline.ObjectInstance..ctor(Object anObject) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Pipeline\ObjectInstance.cs:line
>   30    at
>   StructureMap.Configuration.DSL.Expressions.InstanceExpression`1.IsThis(T
>   obj) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Configuration\DSL\Expressions\InstanceExpression.cs:line
>   223    at
>   StructureMap.Configuration.DSL.Expressions.CreatePluginFamilyExpression`1.Use(PLUGINTYPE
>   object) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Configuration\DSL\Expressions\CreatePluginFamilyExpression.cs:line
>   187    at Sample.Customer.DI.Bootstrapper..ctor() in
>   c:\Sample_Customer\source\Sample.Customer\DI\Bootstrapper.cs:line 25
>   at
>   Sample.Customer.CustomerSessionFactory.<.cctor>b__0(ConfigurationExpression
>   x) in
>   c:\Sample_Customer\source\Sample.Customer\CustomerSessionFactory.cs:line
>   39    at StructureMap.Container.Configure(Action`1 configure) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Container.cs:line
>   323    at StructureMap.ObjectFactory.Configure(Action`1 configure) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\ObjectFactory.cs:line
>   385    at Sample.Customer.CustomerSessionFactory..cctor() in
>   c:\Sample_Customer\source\Sample.Customer\CustomerSessionFactory.cs:line
>   36

please let me know why I am getting this error and how can I resolve it?